# Image should follow touch position using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image and i want the image to move where ever the touch input happens. basically the image should act as a virtual cursor. I already did for mousemove, but the same code doesn't works for touch move.

---

```
/*works for mouse move */   
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        $('img').offset({
            left: e.pageX-55,
            top: e.pageY-45
        });
    });

/* for touch move */
    $(document).touchmove(function(e) {
        $('img').offset({
            left: e.pageX-55,
            top: e.pageY-45
        });
    });
```

expected: image to follow cursor position in desktop and should follow touch position in touch devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider using `.on()` for binding.

```
function moveImg(e){
  console.log(e);
  $('img').offset({
    left: e.pageX-55,
    top: e.pageY-45
  });
}

$(document).on({
  mousemove: moveImg,
  touchmove: moveImg
});
```

Remember `touchmove` is not supported by all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/touchmove_event

`pageX` and `pageY` appear to be part of the touch event, yet if there are more than 1 touch points, it might cause some issues. See More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

> The `TouchEvent` interface encapsulates all of the touch points that are currently active. The `Touch` interface, which represents a single touch point, includes information such as the position of the touch point relative to the browser viewport.

I'm going to do some more testing and update the answer later if needed.

**Update 1**

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hb0awzdy/

Mobile example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hb0awzdy/show/

`touchmove` event is looking for and potentially capturing multiple touch points. So to address this, we want to examine the first one and ignore the other.

```
$(function() {
  function log(eObj) {
    var str = eObj.type + " [" + eObj.top + "," + eObj.left + "]";
    $("#results").html(str);
  }

  function moveCursor(e) {
    var p;
    var o = {
      x: 55,
      y: 45
    };
    if (e.type == "mousemove") {
      p = {
        left: Math.round(e.pageX - o.x),
        top: Math.round(e.pageY - o.y),
        type: e.type
      };
    } else if (e.type == "touchmove") {
      var touch = e.changedTouches[0];
      p = {
        left: Math.round(touch.pageX - o.x),
        top: Math.round(touch.pageY - o.y),
        type: e.type
      }
    }
    $('.cursor').css(p);
    log(p);
  }

  $(document).on({
    mousemove: moveCursor,
    touchmove: moveCursor
  });
});
```

As you can see, the `event.changedTouches` is an array of the various touch points and their attributes. If we focus on `event.changedTouches[0]`, we can get the `pageX` and `pageY` details you're looking for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well the code above works great for normal applications. But to my threejs application, when i implemented it actually points my image apart from te cursor, not matter what values i change it behaves the same.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tzsUxKRvsa8bJotJ8K2hdPvHh3xuC2dT/view

Comment: @JanarthanThumburu I supplied an answer to your question. It looks like you're using it in some other way and didn't bring that up in your original question. If this answers your original question, I hope you will mark it as the answer. How you choose to use it is up to you. If you need more help, you can search around or post another question.